# How do you use a natively compiled Node module in an ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, node-gyp

If you are writing an ES6 module to run in NodeJS, how do you `import` another module that includes natively compiled code?

For example if I set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, do an `npm install talib` and then try to run this:

```
import talib from 'talib';
```

I get this error in Node v16.2.0:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".node" for node_modules/talib/build/Release/talib.node
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:71:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:105:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:243:31)
    at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:21)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:9) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

`talib` is one example but there are a number of others, all of which exhibit the same behaviour.  They all seem to be using `node-gyp` to build.

How can you use these modules in your own ES6 module code?  Do the modules like `talib` and friends need changes?  If so, what should be changed and is it backwards compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly - this works for me:

```
/*eslint-disable */
const talib = require("talib")
/*eslint-enable */
```

Comment: `require()` is the old way of using modules which works fine, the problem is with the new `import` way instead.

Comment: I know - I was not able to figure this out and this is my workaround (with eslint disable) 

/*eslint-disable */
const talib = require("talib")
/*eslint-enable */

Comment: The problem is that if you're writing an ES6 module, you can't use `require()` - it's not a linting problem you can bypass, it flat out won't work as it's not allowed.  Try changing your code to be an ES6 module in `package.json` and you'll see!

Comment: True - but I prefer to have it working rather than correct ;)

Comment: Unfortunately if you're already working on a large ES6 project, refactoring the whole thing to go back to `require()` isn't an option, hence my question :)